# Using jq to parse JSON in launchd

Tags: json, shell, sh, jq

I have a shell script that evaluates a folder full of JSON files which runs fine when invoked directly but fails when run from launchd. Specifically, launchd fails on this line:

```
current_file_snapshots=$(cat $current_file | jq '.snapshots | length')
```

Because:

```
jq: command not found
```

I looked through the jq docs to figure this out, but there's no mention of this problem. I haven't been able to figure out how to get jq (or any similar third party tool) to work through launchd.

Thanks!

Comment: As an aside, this shows a useless use of `cat`. You can use input redirection instead. `$( jq '.snapshots | length' < $current_file)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ahh, looks like I assumed that launchd shared the same PATHs as my normal bash shell. Explicitly spelling out where JQ lives seemed to work:

So at the top of the file I added:

```
JQ=/usr/local/bin/jq
```

and replaced all instances of 'jq' with:

```
$JQ
```

Answer (score 1):

As the very first process that runs in Mac OS X, `launchd` has no environment (including a `PATH` parameter) except for what you specify in `/etc/launchd.conf`. You could create that file and add

```
setenv PATH "/usr/local/bin"
```

If you want the full environment associated with your regular shell sessions, you should execute your script explicitly as a login shell:

```
bash -l myscript.bash
```